# Notification to resume activity which has gone in background using backpress

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-notifications, sinch

we are using Sinch voip api. There is a bound service which starts at app start , we initialize the sinch client in the service and it is always running in the background. I tried putting the code for notification in the call screen activity as this activity will always show to accept the call. My aim is to be able to click on the notification and reopen this call activity like in whatsapp.

```
public class CallScreenActivity extends BaseActivity {

    static final String TAG = CallScreenActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private AudioPlayer mAudioPlayer;
    private Timer mTimer;
    private UpdateCallDurationTask mDurationTask;

    private String mCallId;
    String mCaller, mReceiver;
    String otherusername, myname;
    private long mCallStart = 0;

    private TextView mCallDuration;
    private TextView mCallState;
    private TextView mCallerName;
    private ImageView mCallImg;
    private String mk, mTimestamp;
    private String mProfpic;
    Button endCallButton;

    Notification notification;
    NotificationManager notificationManager; 

    private class UpdateCallDurationTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            CallScreenActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateCallDuration();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                        | +WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | +WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_callscreen);

        mAudioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(this);
        mCallDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callDuration);
        mCallerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remoteUser);
        mCallState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callState);
        mCallImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgotherusr);
        endCallButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hangupButton);

        endCallButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                endCall();
            }
        });
        mCallStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mCallId = getIntent().getStringExtra(SinchCallService.CALL_ID);

        UserSession us = new UserSession(this);
        mk = us.getUserKey();
        myname = us.getUsername();

        mCaller = getIntent().getStringExtra("calleruid");
        mReceiver = getIntent().getStringExtra("receiveruid");
        otherusername = getIntent().getStringExtra("otherusername");
        mTimestamp = getIntent().getStringExtra("timestamp");
        System.out.println(mCaller+"on create call screen activity ongoing call"  + mReceiver + otherusername);

        showNotification();

    }

    private void showNotification() {
        System.out.println("show notification callscreenactivity");
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, CallScreenActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction("ongoingcall");
        notificationIntent.putExtra("calleruid", mCaller);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("receiveruid", mReceiver);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("otherusername", otherusername);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("timestamp", mTimestamp);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent hangupintent = new Intent(this, CallScreenActivity.class);
        hangupintent.setAction("hangupcall");
        hangupintent.setAction("ongoingcall");
        hangupintent.putExtra("calleruid", mCaller);
        hangupintent.putExtra("receiveruid", mReceiver);
        hangupintent.putExtra("otherusername", otherusername);
        hangupintent.putExtra("timestamp", mTimestamp);
        PendingIntent phangupintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                hangupintent, 0);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("In call with " + otherusername)
                .setContentText("Duration " + VoiceCallHelper.formatTimespan(System.currentTimeMillis() - mCallStart))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconcall)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back, "Hangup",
                        phangupintent).build();
        notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(111 /* ID of notification */, notification);

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected() {

        try {
            doStuff();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            //getSinchServiceInterface() in doStuff below throw null pointer error.
        }
    }

    private void doStuff() {
        final Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().getCall(mCallId);
        if (call != null) {
            call.addCallListener(new SinchCallListener());
            mCallState.setText(call.getState().toString());

            DBREF_USER_PROFILES.child(call.getRemoteUserId()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        System.out.println("datasnapshot callscreenactivity otheruser" + dataSnapshot);
                        User u = User.parse(dataSnapshot);
                        mCallerName.setText(u.getName());
                        mProfpic = u.getProfpicurl();
                        Glide.with(CallScreenActivity.this).load(mProfpic).into(mCallImg);

                    } else {
                        mCallerName.setText(call.getHeaders().get("username"));
                        Glide.with(CallScreenActivity.this).load(R.drawable.whatsapplogo).into(mCallImg);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Started with invalid callId, aborting.");
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mDurationTask.cancel();
        mTimer.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mDurationTask = new UpdateCallDurationTask();
        mTimer.schedule(mDurationTask, 0, 500);

        if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getAction() != null) {
            switch (getIntent().getAction()) {
                case "ongoingcall":
                    System.out.println("on resume call screen activity ongoing call" + mCaller + mReceiver + otherusername);
                    mCaller = getIntent().getStringExtra("calleruid");
                    mReceiver = getIntent().getStringExtra("receiveruid");
                    otherusername = getIntent().getStringExtra("otherusername");
                    mTimestamp = getIntent().getStringExtra("timestamp");
                    break;
                case "hangupcall":
                    System.out.println("on resume call screen activity hangup call");
                    mCaller = getIntent().getStringExtra("calleruid");
                    mReceiver = getIntent().getStringExtra("receiveruid");
                    otherusername = getIntent().getStringExtra("otherusername");
                    mTimestamp = getIntent().getStringExtra("timestamp");
                    endCallButton.performClick();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(CallScreenActivity.this, MainAct.class));
    }

    private void endCall() {

        if (notification != null) {
            System.out.println("cancelling notification in endCAll callscreenactivity");
            notificationManager.cancel(111);
        }

        mAudioPlayer.stopProgressTone();
        Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().getCall(mCallId);
        if (call != null) {
            call.hangup();
        }
        finish();
    }

    private void updateCallDuration() {
        if (mCallStart > 0) {
            mCallDuration.setText(VoiceCallHelper.formatTimespan(System.currentTimeMillis() - mCallStart));
            showNotification();
        }
    }

    private class SinchCallListener implements CallListener {

        @Override
        public void onCallEnded(Call call) {
            CallEndCause cause = call.getDetails().getEndCause();
            Log.d(TAG, "Call ended. Reason: " + cause.toString() + mk + mCaller);
            if (mk != null && mCaller != null && mk.matches(mCaller)) {
                mAudioPlayer.stopProgressTone();
                setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);
                String endMsg = "Call ended: " + call.getDetails().toString();
                Long gt = GetTimeStamp.Id();
                Toast.makeText(CallScreenActivity.this, endMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println(endMsg + "mtimestamp" + mTimestamp);

                String cau;
                String oth;


                if (call.getDetails().getDuration() > 0)
                    cau = "completed";
                else
                    cau = cause.toString();

                CallDetails cd1 = new CallDetails(String.valueOf(call.getDetails().getDuration()), mCaller, mReceiver, cau, String.valueOf(gt), mTimestamp, mProfpic, mCallerName.getText().toString());
                CallDetails cd2 = new CallDetails(String.valueOf(call.getDetails().getDuration()), mCaller, mReceiver, cau, String.valueOf(gt), mTimestamp, mProfpic, myname);
                System.out.println(mCaller + "end msg callscreenactivity" + mReceiver + " " + String.valueOf(gt));
                System.out.println("end msg callscreenactivity" + mReceiver + " " + DBREF.child("VoiceCalls").child(mCaller).child(String.valueOf(gt)));

                //setting in mCaller mykey node at voicecalls node firebase
                DBREF_CALLS.child(mCaller).child(String.valueOf(gt)).setValue(cd1);
                //setting in mReceiver otheruserkey node at voicecalls node firebase
                DBREF_CALLS.child(mReceiver).child(String.valueOf(gt)).setValue(cd2);
            }
            endCall();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCallEstablished(Call call) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Call established");
            mAudioPlayer.stopProgressTone();
            mCallState.setText(call.getState().toString());
            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
            mCallStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mTimestamp = GetTimeStamp.timeStamp();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCallProgressing(Call call) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Call progressing");
            mAudioPlayer.playProgressTone();
        }

        @Override
        public void onShouldSendPushNotification(Call call, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {
            // Send a push through your push provider here, e.g. GCM
        }
    }
}
```

My SinchCallService class is this:

```
public class SinchCallService extends Service {

    private static final String APP_KEY = SINCH_APPLICATION_KEY;
    private static final String APP_SECRET = SINCH_SECRET_KEY;
    private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox.sinch.com";

    public static final String LOCATION = "LOCATION";
    public static final String CALL_ID = "CALL_ID";
    static final String TAG = SinchCallService.class.getSimpleName();

    private SinchServiceInterface mSinchServiceInterface = new SinchServiceInterface();
    private SinchClient mSinchClient;
    private String mUserId;

    private StartFailedListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        UserSession us = new UserSession(this);
        System.out.println("From sinchcall oncreate" + us.getUserKey());
        if (!isStarted()) {
            System.out.println("sinch not started callservice oncreate " + us.getUserKey());
            start(us.getUserKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted()) {
            mSinchClient.terminate();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    public void start(String userName) {
        System.out.println("sinch call service start " + userName);
        if (mSinchClient == null) {
            mUserId = userName;
            mSinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(getApplicationContext()).userId(userName)
                    .applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                    .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET)
                    .environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

            mSinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
            mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();

            mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(new MySinchClientListener());
            mSinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new SinchCallClientListener());
            mSinchClient.start();
            System.out.println(" sinch client started");
        }
    }

    private void stop() {
        if (mSinchClient != null) {
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }
    }

    private boolean isStarted() {
        return (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted());
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mSinchServiceInterface;
    }

    public class SinchServiceInterface extends Binder {

        public SinchCallService getService() {
            return SinchCallService.this;
        }

        public Call callPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().callPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        }

        public Call callUser(String userId) {
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().callUser(userId);
        }

        public Call callUser(String userId, Map<String, String> headers) {
            if(!isStarted()){
                UserSession us = new UserSession(getApplicationContext());
                startClient(us.getUserKey());
            }
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().callUser(userId, headers);
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return mUserId;
        }

        public boolean isStarted() {
            return SinchCallService.this.isStarted();
        }

        public void startClient(String userName) {
            System.out.println("startClient called sinchcallservice" + userName);

            if (!isStarted()) {
                System.out.println("startClient not started callservice  " + userName);
                start(userName);
            }


        }

        public void stopClient() {
            stop();
        }

        public void setStartListener(StartFailedListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        public Call getCall(String callId) {
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().getCall(callId);
        }
    }

    public interface StartFailedListener {
        void onStartFailed(SinchError error);

        void onStarted();
    }

    private class MySinchClientListener implements SinchClientListener {

        @Override
        public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStartFailed(error);
            }
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient started");
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStarted();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient stopped");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
            switch (level) {
                case Log.DEBUG:
                    Log.d(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.ERROR:
                    Log.e(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.INFO:
                    Log.i(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.VERBOSE:
                    Log.v(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.WARN:
                    Log.w(area, message);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client,
                                                      ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
        }
    }

    private class SinchCallClientListener implements CallClientListener {

        @Override
        public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, Call call) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Incoming call");
            Intent intent = new Intent(SinchCallService.this, IncomingCallScreenActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
            intent.putExtra(LOCATION, call.getHeaders().get("location"));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            SinchCallService.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Following is my BaseActivity.java :

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ServiceConnection {

    private SinchCallService.SinchServiceInterface mSinchServiceInterface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(this, SinchCallService.class), this,
                BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        if (SinchCallService.class.getName().equals(componentName.getClassName())) {
            mSinchServiceInterface = (SinchCallService.SinchServiceInterface) iBinder;
            onServiceConnected();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        if (SinchCallService.class.getName().equals(componentName.getClassName())) {
            mSinchServiceInterface = null;
            onServiceDisconnected();
        }
    }

    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        // for subclasses
    }

    protected void onServiceDisconnected() {
        // for subclasses
    }

    protected SinchCallService.SinchServiceInterface getSinchServiceInterface() {
        return mSinchServiceInterface;
    }

}
```

I have tried things like setting

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

If I backpress on the CallScreenActivity and click on notification, it opens the MainAct not the CallScreenActivity. How to make it open the CallScreenActivity?

I tried a solution with creating a stackbuilder and passing it to pending intent as follows:

```
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(CallScreenActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And also changed the manifest as follows:

```
<activity
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:name=".activity.calls.CallScreenActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:parentActivityName=".activity.main.MainAct">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".activity.main.MainAct"/>
</activity>
```

But the above change leads to app crash with following error:

```
07-06 23:38:52.353 9182-9182/com.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.sinch.android.rtc.calling.CallClient com.sinch.android.rtc.SinchClient.getCallClient()' on a null object reference
at com.app.services.SinchCallService$SinchServiceInterface.getCall(SinchCallService.java:150)
at com.app.activity.calls.CallScreenActivity.endCall(CallScreenActivity.java:265)
at com.app.activity.calls.CallScreenActivity.access$100(CallScreenActivity.java:51)
at com.app.activity.calls.CallScreenActivity$1.onClick(CallScreenActivity.java:110)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

So If i am using the code without the stackbuilder and i press home button, then press the notification my CallSCreenACtivity opens, but if i press back button inside the CAllSCreenACtivity and then press home button then i press notification, it opens the main acitivty instead of the CallSCreenACtivity. My call is still actvity even after pressing the backbutton on callscreenactivty.

Also I have noticed that the duration of the call being shown in the notification has stopped refreshing after back press on the CallScreenActivity but the call is still active.

Flow of the app:

For Caller:-
When app starts, MainAct starts,from where a user clicks on someone's profile and is taken to ProfilesAct where he presses the call button to call that person and is taken to the CallScreenActivity.

```
MainAct->ProfilesACt->CallScreenACt
```

For Receiver:-
App is in background, the call comes, the SinchCallService makes the IncomingCAllAct to show, when he accepts the call he is taken to the CallScreenActivity.

```
IncomingCallAct->CallSCreeenACtivity
```

or could be suppose receiver is already using the app, then

```
any activity(could be chat activity, main acitivty etc)->IncomingCallAct->CallSCreeenACtivity
```

Manifest of the app:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.t">

    <application
        android:name=".TApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashAct"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

     <activity
            android:name=".activity.userprofile.UserProfileAct"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


        <activity
            android:name=".activity.videocalls.VideoCallScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"/>

        <activity
             android:name=".activity.videocalls.IncomingVideoCallScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:noHistory="true"/>


        <activity
            android:name=".activity.main.MainAct"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

            <activity android:name=".activity.chat.ChatActivity" />

        <service android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".activity.settings.SettingsmainActivity" />

        <service android:name=".services.SinchCallService"></service>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.calls.CallScreenActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.calls.IncomingCallScreenActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity android:name=".activity.chat.NewChatActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".activity.chat.ChatActivity1"/>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You override `onBackPressed()` in `CallScreenActivity` and have it start `MainAct`. What is the reason? Is the `MainAct` activity already running (ie: underneath `CallScreenActivity`? You need to explain the navigation between your activites. Be aware that using `TaskStackBuilder` is probably not what you want, as this will always clear the task and dump any running activities (which is probably not what you want).

Comment: @DavidWasser i have included the flow of the app now, can you please help me?

Comment: What should happen when the user pressed BACK in `CallScreenActivity`? Is `MainAct` still active (not finished) when `CallScreenActivity` is running? I still don't understand your problem.

Comment: Also post your manifest. Also you call `addAction()` twice on `hangupintent` in `showNotification()` that will also not work as the second call overwrites the first.

Comment: @DavidWasser hi, when the user presses the backbutton the mainactvity should open, after that if he wants to return to the call screen activity he should be able to press the notification and the callscreenactivity should resume without starting it as a new activity but resuming it in previous state.

Comment: I see no reason why tapping on the notification should not open `CallScreenActivity`. However, since you launch `MainAct` when the user presses BACK while in `CallScreenActivity`, this will cause a new instance of `MainAct` to be created ON TOP OF `CallScreenActivity`. Then, when the user taps on the `Notification`, it should create a new instance of `CallScreenActivity` which will be ON TOP OF `MainAct` so that you should end up with an activity stack something like this (assuming that you don't call `finish()` when starting new activities:

Comment: ...`MainAct->ProfilesAct->CallScreenActivity->MainAct->CallScreenActivity`. You can check the activity stack by using `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`. You should also add some logging to all  the lifecycle methods (`onCreate()`, `onResume()`, etc.) so that you can really follow what is going on. Do some debugging and then tell us what is happening.

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks for your help!! I tried everything you suggested and logged everything also checked activity stack from adb shell, finally it turned out my callid being passed to the activity was wrong and the finish() was getting called from doStuff() method,  now i have started storing active call data in the shared preferences and it has become much easier to handle the call, notification also working. thanks for giving me your time :)

Comment: Happy you were able to resolve your problem. Please write an answer to your own question that explains what the problem was and how your fixed it. Then accept that answer. This could help others who have a similar problem. It will also take this question off the "unanswered questions list".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to make the CallScreenActivity in the mainfest as singletask or singletop, just store the call parameters like callid(which helps Sinch api in recognizing the specific call), call start time, etc in sharedpreferences or sqlite db, make the notification intent like following :

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallScreenActivity.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
        notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setContentTitle("In call with " + otherusername)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconcall)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(111 /* ID of notification */, notification);
```

As long as we pass the right callid we will be able to resume call by clicking the notification.